# How to sort List which contains more than tow heterogeneous object in java?

Tags: java

Hi I have a list of object which contains four object (Employee,Student,Patient,Customer). I need to sort these list in ascending order based on their corresponding ID.
When I am using `Collections.sort(list)` method is giving ***ClassCastException***.

Below is complete code which I am using...

**Note**: I tried with `Comparator` interface also, but couldn't able to define the logic inside `compare()` method to sort these object. If list contain two object then it is easy to define logic to sort these object inside, but if list contains more than tow object then it is very difficult to define sorting logic inside `compare()` method.

**Can any one help me how to short this list? 
Please modify the below code and provide me the solution. The output should be in sorted order like [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,90]**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Employee(50));
        list.add(new Customer(10));
        list.add(new Patient(60));
        list.add(new Student(90));
        list.add(new Employee(20));
        list.add(new Customer(40));
        list.add(new Patient(70));
        list.add(new Student(30));

        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}

class Patient implements Comparable<Patient>
{

    int pId;

    Patient(int pId)
    {
        this.pId = pId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Patient o)
    {
        return this.pId - o.pId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.pId + "";
    }

}

class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{

    int empId;

    Employee(int empId)
    {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o)
    {
        return this.empId - o.empId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.empId + "";
    }

}

class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>
{

    int cId;

    Customer(int cId)
    {
        this.cId = cId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Customer o)
    {
        return this.cId - o.cId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.cId + "";
    }

}

class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{

    int sId;

    Student(int sId)
    {
        this.sId = sId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o)
    {
        return this.sId - o.sId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.sId + "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a superclass, for example `Person`, and add your `id` there. The compare based on id logic should be implemented there as well.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private int id;

    // getters, setters, compareTo, etc

}
```

Make all your base classes extend from `Person`

```
public class Student extends Person { ... }
public class Customer extends Person { ... }
public class Employee extends Person { ... }
public class Patient extends Person { ... }
```

Define you `List` in terms on `Person` and apply sort on that.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Employee(50));
    list.add(new Customer(10));
    list.add(new Patient(60));
    list.add(new Student(90));
    list.add(new Employee(20));
    list.add(new Customer(40));
    list.add(new Patient(70));
    list.add(new Student(30));

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define an interface `Identifiable` (or a superclass Person), with a method `int getId()`.

Make all your classes implement that interface (or extend that superclass).

Stop using raw types, and thus use a `List<Identifiable>` instead of a `List`.

Then sort the list using a `Comparator<Identifiable>`, which can be defined using `Comparator.comparingInt(Identifiable::getId)`.

All your classes should not implement Comparable. Their ID does not define their *natural* ordering. You just happen to sort them by ID in this specific use-case. And should thus use a specific comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Create class like person which has id attribute. Then extend all theses classes by it. Then You only need to write compare for person class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily just by adding a **common interface** for all your POJOs, define a method to get the id and then write a custom comparator for comparing.

Heres the rewritten version which sorts the Object.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


class Test {    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Employee(50));
    list.add(new Customer(10));
    list.add(new Patient(60));
    list.add(new Student(90));
    list.add(new Employee(20));
    list.add(new Customer(40));
    list.add(new Patient(70));
    list.add(new Student(30));

    Collections.sort(list, new IDComparator());

    Stream.of(list).forEach(System.out::println);

}
}


class Patient implements CommonObject {

int pId;

Patient(int pId) {
    this.pId = pId;
}


@Override
public int getId() {
    return this.pId;
}
}

class Employee implements CommonObject {

int empId;

Employee(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

@Override
public int getId() {
    return this.empId;
}


}

class Customer implements CommonObject {

int cId;

Customer(int cId) {
    this.cId = cId;
}


@Override
public int getId() {
    return this.cId;
}

}

class Student implements CommonObject {

int sId;

Student(int sId) {
    this.sId = sId;
}

@Override
public int getId() {
    return this.sId;
}

}
```

**Now Custom Comparator:**

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class IDComparator implements Comparator<CommonObject> {

@Override
public int compare(CommonObject o1, CommonObject o2) {
    if (o1.getId() == o2.getId())
        return 0;
    else if (o1.getId() > o2.getId())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
}
```

**Common Object Interface:**

```
public interface CommonObject {
int getId();
}
```

Tested, Heres the output of above code:

> [Customer@23223dd8, Employee@4ec6a292, Student@1b40d5f0,
>   Customer@ea4a92b, Employee@3c5a99da, Patient@47f37ef1,
>   Patient@5a01ccaa, Student@71c7db30]

Thanks, any suggestions are most welcome.